# Finding unique points in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

What is a faster way of finding unique x,y points (removing duplicates) in a numpy array like:

```
points = numpy.random.randint(0, 5, (10,2))
```

I thought of converting points to a complex numbers and then checking for unique, but that seems rather convoluted:

```
b = numpy.unique(points[:,0] + 1j * points[:,1])
points = numpy.column_stack((b.real, b.imag))
```

Comment: If you don't require order to be preserved, use tuples for the points and convert the list to a set.

Comment: I need the result to be a numpy array, so that seems like a lot of conversions.

Comment: Is there a real reason why the simple solution `numpy.vstack([numpy.array(u) for u in set([tuple(p) for p in points])])` is not fast enough?

Comment: Thinking there must be a faster way than list comprehension when it gets to longer lists of points, no?

Comment: Wim's method is faster, especially for larger arrays. Probably because it doesn't bother sorting the result. I added some timeit benchmarks to my post. Perhaps wim will post his solution as an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would do it like this:

`numpy.array(list(set(tuple(p) for p in points)))`

For the fast solution in the most general case, maybe this recipe would interest you:
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52560-remove-duplicates-from-a-sequence/

Comment: I have a similar problem for which this works a charm but it comes out unsorted, even though the data went in sorted. Why does this happen?

Comment: Because the ordering is destroyed by `set`, which is an unordered collection.

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from sorting the output, though  :)   The set is only used as an intermediate step to remove dupes here.

Answer (score 7):

I think you have a very good idea here. Think about the underlying block of memory used to represent the data in `points`. We tell numpy to regard that block as representing an array of shape (10,2) with dtype `int32` (32-bit integers), but it is almost costless to tell numpy to regard that same block of memory as representing an array of shape (10,) with dtype `c8` (64-bit complex).

So the only real cost is calling `np.unique`, followed by another virtually costless call to `view` and `reshape`:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)
points = np.random.randint(0, 5, (10,2))
print(points)
print(len(points))
```

yields

```
[[3 4]
 [0 1]
 [3 0]
 [0 1]
 [4 4]
 [1 2]
 [4 2]
 [4 3]
 [4 2]
 [4 2]]
10
```

while

```
cpoints = points.view('c8')
cpoints = np.unique(cpoints)
points = cpoints.view('i4').reshape((-1,2))
print(points)
print(len(points))
```

yields

```
[[0 1]
 [1 2]
 [3 0]
 [3 4]
 [4 2]
 [4 3]
 [4 4]]
7
```

---

If you don't need the result to be sorted, wim's method is faster (You might want to consider accepting his answer...)

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)
N=10000
points = np.random.randint(0, 5, (N,2))

def using_unique():
    cpoints = points.view('c8')
    cpoints = np.unique(cpoints)
    return cpoints.view('i4').reshape((-1,2))

def using_set():
    return np.vstack([np.array(u) for u in set([tuple(p) for p in points])])
```

yields these benchmarks:

```
% python -mtimeit -s'import test' 'test.using_set()'
100 loops, best of 3: 18.3 msec per loop
% python -mtimeit -s'import test' 'test.using_unique()'
10 loops, best of 3: 40.6 msec per loop
```

Comment: np.unique sorts the result. Are you looking for a method which keeps the remaining elements in order?

Comment: No, I mean, I obtain the wrong result: cpoints.shape is still 10,2 and the final points do not match the original.

Comment: I've edited the post to show it does work for at least one seed. Can you show an example where it does not work (with a seed so the problem is reproducible)?

Comment: Not what I'm seeing... Pyhton 2.7.1, numpy 2.0.0. I'm getting the same result with Python 2.6.7 and numpy 1.5.1 and with Python 2.7.1 and numpy 1.5.1 (on mac), which is [[0,0],[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[4,0]]... Hmm.

Comment: But runs fine on my old Python 2.5.6 with numpy 1.2.1. Any idea what might be causing this? Thanks for a nice answer, btw.

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7.2, and numpy 1.5.1. I checked the documentation for [np.unique on numpy 2.0.0](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html#numpy-unique) versus [np.unique on numpy 1.5.1](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.5.x/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html). They appear the same, so I have no idea why they should behave differently. It would help immensely if you could provide a simple example of an array on which the method does not work (either be specifying `np.random.seed(...)` or a concrete `points` array.)

Comment: Not that anyone will C, but recarrays might be nicer then just a larger dtype (and more general)