# Scipy: Sparse Matrix giving incorrect values

Tags: numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

Below is my code for generating my sparse matrix:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy

def sparsemaker(X, Y, Z):
    'X, Y, and Z are 2D arrays of the same size'
    x_, row = np.unique(X, return_inverse=True)
    y_, col = np.unique(Y, return_inverse=True)
    return scipy.sparse.csr_matrix( (Z.flat,(row,col)), shape=(x_.size, y_.size) )

>>> print sparsemaker(A, B, C) #A, B, and C are (220, 256) sized arrays.
(0, 0)  167064.269831
(0, 2)  56.6146564629
(0, 9)  53.8660340698
(0, 23) 80.6529717039
(0, 28) 0.0
(0, 33) 53.2379218326
(0, 40) 54.3868995375
 :          :
```

Now my input arrays are a bit large, so i don't know how to post them here (unless anyone has any ideas); but even looking at the first value, i can already tell something is wrong:

```
>>> test = sparsemaker(A, B, C)
>>> np.max(test.toarray())
167064.26983076424

>>> np.where(C==np.max(test.toarray()))
(array([], dtype=int64), array([], dtype=int64))
```

Does anyone know why this would happen? Where did that value come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have repeated coordinates, and the constructor is adding them all up. Do the following :

```
x_, row = np.unique(X, return_inverse=True)
y_, col = np.unique(Y, return_inverse=True)
print Z.flat[(row == 0) & (col == 0)].sum()
```

and you should get that mysterious `167064.26983076424` printed out.

**EDIT** The ugly code that follows works fine with small examples in averaging repeated entries, with some code borrowed from [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560440/removing-duplicate-columns-and-rows-from-a-numpy-2d-array), give it a try:

```
def sparsemaker(X, Y, Z):
    'X, Y, and Z are 2D arrays of the same size'
    x_, row = np.unique(X, return_inverse=True)
    y_, col = np.unique(Y, return_inverse=True)
    indices = np.array(zip(row, col))
    _, repeats = np.unique(indices.view([('', indices.dtype)]*2),
                           return_inverse=True)
    counts = 1. / np.bincount(repeats)
    factor = counts[repeats]

    return scipy.sparse.csr_matrix((Z.flat * factor,(row,col)),
                                   shape=(x_.size, y_.size))
```

Comment: Good eye, @Jamie...This is going to be a problem. Would you know of a way to **average** the duplicates instead of sum them?

Comment: @NoobSaibot Try the code in my edit, see how slowly it works in your real cases.

Comment: @Jamie, it works *perfectly*! I don't know what i would do without this site...seriously. Thank you.