# Cython: "fatal error: numpy/arrayobject.h: No such file or directory"

Tags: python, windows-7, numpy, cython

I'm trying to speed up the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14469557/1658908) using Cython. I try to compile the code (after doing the `cygwinccompiler.py` hack explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034390/compiling-with-cython-and-mingw-produces-gcc-error-unrecognized-command-line-o/6035864#6035864)), but get a `fatal error: numpy/arrayobject.h: No such file or directory...compilation terminated` error. Can anyone tell me if it's a problem with my code, or some esoteric subtlety with Cython?

Below is my code.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython

cdef inline np.ndarray[np.int, ndim=1] fbincount(np.ndarray[np.int_t, ndim=1] x):
    cdef int m = np.amax(x)+1
    cdef int n = x.size
    cdef unsigned int i
    cdef np.ndarray[np.int_t, ndim=1] c = np.zeros(m, dtype=np.int)

    for i in xrange(n):
        c[<unsigned int>x[i]] += 1

    return c

cdef packed struct Point:
    np.float64_t f0, f1

@cython.boundscheck(False)
def sparsemaker(np.ndarray[np.float_t, ndim=2] X not None,
                np.ndarray[np.float_t, ndim=2] Y not None,
                np.ndarray[np.float_t, ndim=2] Z not None):

    cdef np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] counts, factor
    cdef np.ndarray[np.int_t, ndim=1] row, col, repeats
    cdef np.ndarray[Point] indices

    cdef int x_, y_

    _, row = np.unique(X, return_inverse=True); x_ = _.size
    _, col = np.unique(Y, return_inverse=True); y_ = _.size
    indices = np.rec.fromarrays([row,col])
    _, repeats = np.unique(indices, return_inverse=True)
    counts = 1. / fbincount(repeats)
    Z.flat *= counts.take(repeats)

    return sp.sparse.csr_matrix((Z.flat,(row,col)), shape=(x_, y_)).toarray()
```

Comment: can you add a tag for what OS you are using?

Comment: @tcaswell 64-bit Windows 7.

Comment: added the windows tag, hopefully that will help this problem be seen by people who know how to use windows (unlike me).

Comment: I found [this](http://wiki.cython.org/64BitCythonExtensionsOnWindows). Some of the terminology is above my head, but i'm gonna check it out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make distutils look for numpy header files in the correct place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379898/make-distutils-look-for-numpy-header-files-in-the-correct-place)

Answer (score 268, accepted):

In your `setup.py`, the `Extension` should have the argument `include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()]`.

Also, you are missing `np.import_array()` in your code.

--

**Example setup.py:**

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy

setup(
    ext_modules=[
        Extension("my_module", ["my_module.c"],
                  include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()]),
    ],
)

# Or, if you use cythonize() to make the ext_modules list,
# include_dirs can be passed to setup()

setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize("my_module.pyx"),
    include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()]
)
```

Comment: Why would i need `np.import_array()`? Isn't that for the [Numpy C-API](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.html)?

Comment: I tried your idea, but now i get this crazy error that is too long to post here, but it starts with `warning: untitled.pyx:8:49: Buffer unpacking not optimized away.`

Comment: Ah, true, you probably don't need `np.import_array()`. I rarely write numpy-using Cython extensions without it, though, so I use it as a matter of habit. As for your other problem, what you quoted is just a warning, not an error. If you have other errors that need fixing, please make a new post.

Comment: `include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()]` is a nice trick thank you!

Comment: definitely helped me building a point cloud library (PCL) python wrapper that is using Numpy and Cython, however, there are warnings `Using deprecated NumPy API` - is this deprecated?

Comment: What I advised is not deprecated, and it's possible that you aren't using any deprecated API functions either. [The documentation describes why you get this message and what you can do about it.](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/c-api.deprecations.html)

Comment: I've added a working example, as it wasn't clear to me where exactly I had to add the include_dirs directive.

Comment: `include_dirs` passed to `setup()` gets ignored in the latest distutils, it has to be passed to each `Extension`, at least on mac

Comment: I get a `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'import_array'` error if doing `np.import_array()` in the python code calling the cython module...

Comment: Thanks for this; it seems this critical step is missing from the cython documentation!

Answer (score 53):

For a one-file project like yours, another alternative is to use `pyximport`. You don't need to create a `setup.py` ... you don't need to even open a command line if you use IPython ... it's all very convenient. In your case, try running these commands in IPython or in a normal Python script:

```
import numpy
import pyximport
pyximport.install(setup_args={"script_args":["--compiler=mingw32"],
                              "include_dirs":numpy.get_include()},
                  reload_support=True)

import my_pyx_module

print my_pyx_module.some_function(...)
...
```

You may need to edit the compiler of course. This makes import and reload work the same for `.pyx` files as they work for `.py` files.

Source: http://wiki.cython.org/InstallingOnWindows

Comment: Thanks, @SteveB. But can you elaborate a bit on what you mean by "_For a one-file project like yours_..."? The module above is one (albeit important) part of a larger application. How does `pyximport` affect my code's speed? And finally, the section here: ["_Since Cython 0.11, the pyximport module also has experimental compilation support for normal Python modules_..."](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/tutorial.html#pyximport-cython-compilation-the-easy-way) implies that it still has some kinks to work out. Can you explain that as well?

Comment: Re "experimental compilation support for normal Python modules" -- with the code I suggested above, `.py` modules are compiled normally (not with cython) while `.pyx` modules are compiled with cython. If you pass `pyimport = True` into `pyximport.install()`, then it will use cython for everything, even for example `import random` or `import os`. I don't suggest using that feature, simply because there's no compelling reason to use it, and it could create problems. It's probably used mainly by cython developers.

Comment: If `pyximport` works at all, it will create the exact same C code as any other method. So try it and see. I was referring to the fact that when the compilation process is sufficiently complicated, e.g. links to external system libraries, you might find that pyximport fails and you need a `setup.py` and `cythonize` to specify exactly how to build it. But the fact that your `.pyx` module has `import`s or `cimport`s does not mean that it can't be compiled with `pyximport`; it may well be totally fine.

Comment: This works great! But I recommend --compiler=msvc if you already have msvc installed. Then you don't need to install mingw.

Answer (score 21):

The error means that a numpy header file isn't being found during compilation.

Try doing `export CFLAGS=-I/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/`, and then compiling.  This is a problem with a few different packages.  There's a bug filed in ArchLinux for the same issue: https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/22326

Comment: Where do i add the `export` line? In my `setup.py` file?

Comment: No, it's a shell command. Run it in your shell, then start compiling.

Comment: @NoobSaibot in the shell (where you run `python setup.py`) run the `export ..` command first.  It sets the environmental variables of the shell, not anything directly to do with [pc]ython.

Comment: @tcaswell: I figured as much. I'm using cmd, and got this `'export' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` error...just can't win with this one...

Comment: @NoobSaibot you are getting lunix answers for what smells like a windows problem....

Comment: Right... I'm sure there's a windows equivalent, I just have no idea what it is.

Comment: Actually, in Windows you should be able to add that path to the PATH environmental variable.  Should be in system properties > environmental variables.

Comment: The problem is not specific to Windows. I just came across this same error on a Unix machine.

Comment: alternatively you can add this to the `gcc` command: `/usr/bin/gcc -shared -fPIC -Os -I/usr/include/python3.5m/ -I/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/include/ -o mymodule.so mymodule.c`

Comment: I have a [Cython post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41944883/verifying-compatibility-in-compiling-extension-types-and-using-them-with-cdef) you may be able to provide insight on.

Comment: This works for me in Windows, should be cross-platform.  Add to your `setup.py`:
 `import os; import numpy; os.putenv('INCLUDE', numpy.get_headers())`

Answer (score 4):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44888925/fatal-error-numpy-arrayobject-h-no-such-file-or-directory/44935933), if you have installed `numpy` with `pip` on Linux, you will need to manually set a symbolic link to `/usr/include/numpy`

In my case the path is:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ /usr/include/numpy
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are too lazy to write setup files and figure out the path for include directories, 
try [cyper](https://github.com/syrte/cyper). It can compile your Cython code and set `include_dirs` for Numpy automatically.

Load your code into a string, then simply run `cymodule = cyper.inline(code_string)`, then your function is available as `cymodule.sparsemaker` instantaneously. Something like this

```
code = open(your_pyx_file).read()
cymodule = cyper.inline(code)

cymodule.sparsemaker(...)
# do what you want with your function
```

You can install cyper via `pip install cyper`.

Answer (score 1):

#### Simple answer

A way simpler way is to add the path to your file `distutils.cfg`. It's path behalf of Windows 7 is by default `C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\`. You just assert the following contents and it should work out:

```
[build_ext]
include_dirs= C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include
```

#### Entire config file

To give you an example how the config file could look like, my entire file reads:

```
[build]
compiler = mingw32

[build_ext]
include_dirs= C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include
compiler = mingw32
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be able to do it within `cythonize()` function as mentioned [here](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#configuring-the-c-build), but it doesn't work beacuse there is a [known issue](https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/1480)

Answer (score -1):

I hadn't sudo privileges on the server I was running and export CFLAGS didn't work with me. For sake of simplicity, I've installed Anaconda (
https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/) which creates links to all its installed packages, including Numpy. You can also install miniconda and work with environments to avoid using too much space.

Comment: Are you sure this answers the question? Please read [answer].