# Cython compilation error with include_path as a keyword in cythonize

Tags: python, cython

I have a code snippet, called 'test.pyx':

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

print(np.arange(10))
```

And then I wrote two `setup.py` to compile them. The first one worked fine:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy as np

extensions = [
    Extension('test', ['test.pyx'], include_dirs = [np.get_include()]),
    ]

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize(extensions)
    )
```

And this one did not work (which is also from an example on http://docs.cython.org/src/reference/compilation.html):

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy as np


setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize('./test.pyx', include_path=[np.get_include()])
    )
```

It says: ./test.c(346) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'numpy/arrayobject.h': No such file or directory.

I am using Python 3.3 64-bit on Windows 64-bit, with WinSDK 7.1.

Comment: did you check if the file `arrayobject.h` is there? You can also try to add the path obtained with `np.get_include()` to the environment variable `INCLUDE`

Comment: Got the same problem. The file is there.

Comment: I have same problem. Your first solution saved me. Ubuntu Anaconda python 2.7

Comment: I'm surprised the cython docs are outdated or with wrong snippets. See this answer for a working alternative: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14657667/140510

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a Cython documentation bug, see also https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/1480

Comment: To be short, use `include_path` for cythonize instead