# Sympy's autowrap with cython and Matrix generates fatal error: 'numpy/arrayobject.h' file not found

Tags: cython, sympy

I'm trying to execute the simple example from the Sympy's autowrap module that includes matrix/vector product with the Cython langage (since I do not have gfortran installed):

```
import sympy.utilities.autowrap as aw
from sympy.utilities.autowrap import autowrap
from sympy import symbols, IndexedBase, Idx, Eq
A, x, y = map(IndexedBase, ['A', 'x', 'y'])
m, n = symbols('m n', integer=True)
i = Idx('i', m)
j = Idx('j', n)
instruction = Eq(y[i], A[i, j]*x[j])
matvec = autowrap(instruction, language='C',backend='cython')
```

I'm on OSX 10.9.4, with the anaconda distribution for python 2.7, sympy 0.7.6.1 and cython 0.23.2.

I get the following (known) error: *fatal error: 'numpy/arrayobject.h' file not found*

It seems to be a systematic error, and one needs to include the appropriate numpy's header target in the setup file attached to the compilation process of cython as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14657375/cython-fatal-error-numpy-arrayobject-h-no-such-file-or-directory).

How to get rid form this issue in an *autowrap* context?
It seems this is a bug fixed [here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/8848), but it does not work for me... Is this bug fix included in sympy's realease 0.7.6.1?
Any idea?

Comment: Are you using the development version of SymPy?

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug and is now fixed. See this pull request:

https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/8848

If you use the development version of SymPy, it should work. Else you could have autowrap spit the files out to a temporary directory, add the correct include statement to the generated files, and manually compile the code.