# VSCode: "fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory" even with python-dev installed

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio-code, python-extensions

Using VSCode (which I'm quite new to) on Ubuntu 20.04, I wish to build a C-extension (actually C++ extension) to Python.

I'm trying to build the following MWE:

```
#include <numpy/arrayobject.h>
int main() {return 0;}
```

However the build fails on `#include <numpy/arrayobject.h>` with the error

> /usr/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:11:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

I do have `python3.9-dev` installed, and my `c_cpp_properties.json` is supposed to contain the relevant path to include:

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/usr/include/python3.9",
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-clang-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

This question was supposedly answered plenty of times in the past, and yet nothing works for me from any answer I found.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `c_cpp_properties.json` has nothing to do with the compiler. The file you need to edit to affect the compiler is `tasks.json`.

Comment: @john Can you elaborate on the required change? Can I make g++ look inside `/usr/include/python3.9` by default?

Comment: Your `tasks.json` file contains arguments passed to the compiler g++. Judging by your question above, you need to add the argument `"-I/usr/include/python3.9"`

Comment: @john Thank you for your help. Adding that argument in the beginning of the `"args"` list, I now get another errors: 1. ```/usr/include/python3.9/object.h:430: undefined reference to `_Py_Dealloc'```. 2. ```/usr/include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1466: undefined reference to `PyImport_ImportModule'```

Comment: Well those are link errors. Again the solution will be one or more additional arguments to tasks.json to link with the correct libraries. Not knowing much about python I have no idea what those might be. Probably worth a new question, and this time include your tasks.json file in the question.

Comment: @john Thanks. I'll try digging from here again.

Comment: `includePath` for numpy is to short. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66984745/1387438