# Identify duplicate rows in an array and sum up corresponding values in another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, duplicates, unique

Suppose there is an array with outcomes and an array with probabilities. It can be the case that some outcomes are listed multiple times. For example:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array(([0,0],[1,1],[2,1],[1,1],[2,2]),dtype=int)
p = np.array([0.1,0.2,0.3,0.1,0.2],dtype=float)
```

Now I would like to list the unique outcomes in `x` and add up the corresponding probabilities in `p` of the duplicate outcomes. So the result should be arrays `xnew` and `pnew` defined as

```
xnew = np.array(([0,0],[1,1],[2,1],[2,2]),dtype=int)
pnew = np.array([0.1,0.3,0.3,0.2],dtype=float)
```

While there are some examples of how to obtain unique rows, see, e.g. [Removing duplicate columns and rows from a NumPy  2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560440/removing-duplicate-columns-and-rows-from-a-numpy-2d-array) , it is unclear to me how to use this to add up values in the other array.

Anyone have a suggestion? Solutions using numpy are preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bincount` can sum the `p` array for you, you just need to create a unique id number for every unique row in a. If you're using a sorting approach to identify the unique rows, than creating a unique id is really easy. Once you have sorted the rows generated a diff array, you can just `cumsum` the diff array. For example:

```
  x    diff cumsum
[0, 0]  1    1
[0, 0]  0    1
[0, 1]  1    2
[0, 2]  1    3
[1, 0]  1    4
[1, 0]  0    4
[1, 0]  0    4
[1, 0]  0    4
[1, 0]  0    4
[1, 1]  1    5
```

In code, it looks like this:

```
import numpy as np

def unique_rows(a, p):
    order = np.lexsort(a.T)
    a = a[order]
    diff = np.ones(len(a), 'bool')
    diff[1:] = (a[1:] != a[:-1]).any(-1)
    sums = np.bincount(diff.cumsum() - 1, p[order])
    return a[diff], sums
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical grouping problem, which can be solved in a fully vectorized manner using the [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclosure: I am its author):

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
xnew, pnew = npi.group_by(x).sum(p)
```

Comment: Nice package. This functionaility could be useful to include in numpy itself.

Comment: Thanks; I initially wrote is as a numpy enhancement proposal, but grappling with all the backwards compatibility questions would probably take longer than id be willing to wait. I do hope this functionality gets backported to numpy eventually though.

Answer (score 0):

Not using numpy, but collecting similar value could be done with a dictionary,

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array(([0,0],[1,1],[2,1],[1,1],[2,2]),dtype=int)
p = np.array([0.1,0.2,0.3,0.1,0.2],dtype=float)

#Initialise dictonary
pdict = {}
for i in x:
    pdict[str(i)] = []

#Collect same values using keys
for i in range(x.shape[0]):
    pdict[str(x[i])].append(p[i])

#Sum over keys
xnew = []; pnew = []
for key, val in pdict.items():
    xnew.append(key)
    pnew.append(np.sum(val))

print('xnew = ',np.array(xnew))
print('pnew = ',np.array(pnew))
```

I've left the xnew values as strings which could be converted back to lists with some form of split.

Comment: This is similar to the solution that I already use and I'm trying to get an alternative for. I'm using defaultdict for this. `pdict = defaultdict(float)` and in the for loop set `pdict[tuple(x[i])] += p[i]`. However, this isn't a vectorized operation, which is preferred for me.