# How to find the number of unique elements in a list of ndarrays?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a `list` of `ndarray`s and I want to find the number of unique `ndarrays` in it.

For example:

```
l = [ np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([2,3,4]), np.array([1,2,3]) ]
l
=> [array([1, 2, 3]), array([2, 3, 4]), np.array([1,2,3])]

np.unique(l) expected outcome:
=> [array([1, 2, 3]), array([2, 3, 4])]
```

When I try to use np.unique() I get `TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'`

Can anyone suggest an efficient way to get this? (I can use `map`, calc some hash value from the arrays and run `up.unique` on that, but I'm wondering if there is a better way.)

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Efficiently count the number of occurrences of unique subarrays in NumPy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30879446/efficiently-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-unique-subarrays-in-numpy)

Comment: first of all, your arrays in `l` are in **1d**, can you show what `ndarray` you actually tried to get unique out of it and what is your expected outcome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast the arrays to tuples:

```
 len(set([tuple(v) for v in l]))
```

Comment: works. thanks! can anyone share about efficiency of this for large l and/or large subarrays (what's the cost of tuple(v)?) ?