# count frequency in nested numpy array

Tags: python, image, opencv, numpy

I want to count the same pixel frequency of a image.
the src ndarray:

```
[
 [1, 2, 3],
 [1, 2, 3],
 [5, 6, 7]
]
```

The result i want is:

```
[
 [1, 2, 3, 2],
 [5, 6, 7, 1]
]
```

But the numpy.unique or numpy.bincount can't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30879446/efficiently-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-unique-subarrays-in-numpy

Comment: it's great. but i also want to count the same pixel

Comment: Linked a more relevant question that deals with counts. Did you check out the latest linked question?

Comment: Yeah. I check the lastest question, and it work perfectly. Thanks Divakar

Comment: oh. I just get the result like (72370, 8), (72371, 20), (72372, 6). Image pixel seem to nested with 3 level.@Divakar

Answer (score 0):

Would this work.

```
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np
In [17]: freq = Counter(np.array(lst).flatten())
In [18]: freq
Out[18]: Counter({1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 2, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1})
```

Comment: Doesn't look like that's the desired output.  Each row in the matrix is considered a unique "value", and you want to count how many times you see each "value".

Answer (score 0):

Are you dealing with RGB values in the [0..255] range? In this case you may try this.

You start from:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[5,6,7]])
```

Create a bijection between ([0..255],[0..255],[0..255]) and [0..16777215]:

```
a_ = a[:,0]*256**2 + a[:,1]*256 + a[:,0]
```

Apply bincount:

```
b_ = np.bincount(a_)
```

Apply the reciprocal bijection:

```
h = []
for i,e in enumerate(b_):
    if e:
      b = i%256
      g = (i//256)%256
      r = i/65536
      h.append([r,g,b,e])
```

What you want will be in h

Comment: Really thanks. Infact what I want is  converting this code to python: index = (unsigned char) gray->imageData[i * gray->widthStep + j];

Comment: gray is a grayscale image. and i is height, j is width