# Sort NumPy float array column by column

Tags: python, numpy

Following [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7989722/finding-unique-points-in-numpy-array) to grab unique entries for a NumPy array, I now have a two-column array, basically of pairs with first element in the range [0.9:0.02:1.1] and the second element in the range [1.5:0.1:2.0]. Let's call this `A`. Currently, it's completely unsorted, i.e.

```
In [111]: A
Out[111]: 
array([[ 1.1 ,  1.9 ],
       [ 1.06,  1.9 ],
       [ 1.08,  1.9 ],
       [ 1.08,  1.6 ],
       [ 0.9 ,  1.8 ],
       ...
       [ 1.04,  1.6 ],
       [ 0.96,  2.  ],
       [ 0.94,  2.  ],
       [ 0.98,  1.9 ]])
```

I'd like to sort it so that each row first increases in the second column, then the first. i.e.

```
array([[ 0.9 ,  1.5 ],
       [ 0.9 ,  1.6 ],
       [ 0.9 ,  1.7 ],
       [ 0.9 ,  1.9 ],
       [ 0.9 ,  1.9 ],
       [ 0.9 ,  2.  ],
       [ 0.92,  1.5 ],
       ...
       [ 1.08,  2.  ],
       [ 1.1 ,  1.5 ],
       [ 1.1 ,  1.6 ],
       [ 1.1 ,  1.7 ],
       [ 1.1 ,  1.8 ],
       [ 1.1 ,  1.9 ],
       [ 1.1 ,  2.  ]])
```

but I can't find a sort algorithm that gives both. As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828059/sorting-arrays-in-numpy-by-column), I've tried `A[A[:,0].argsort()]` and `A[A[:,1].argsort()]`, but they only sort one column each. I've also tried applying both but the same thing happens.

I apologize if I've missed something simple but I've been looking for this for a while now...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`numpy.lexsort`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html#numpy.lexsort) will work here:

```
A[np.lexsort(A.T)]
```

You need to transpose `A` before passing it to lexsort because when passed a 2d array it expects to sort by rows (last row, second last row, etc).

The alternative possibly slightly clearer way is to pass the columns explicitly:

```
A[np.lexsort((A[:, 0], A[:, 1]))]
```

You still need to remember that lexsort sorts by the last key first (there's probably some good reason for this; it's the same as performing a stable sort on successive keys).

Comment: Seems `np.lexsort`is quite a bit faster then `np.sort` on recarrays... So I would only add as a suggestion that the unique part can be done most efficiently after sorting.

Comment: lexsort actually sorts on the keys in order, but the last key sorted on will be the primary key, second to last the secondary key, etc.

Answer (score 4):

the following will work, but there might be a faster way:

```
A = np.array(sorted(A,key=tuple))
```

Comment: @seberg -- hence "but there might be a faster way".  This has the advantage that it is easy to read if speed isn't an issue.  However, I'm a little surprised that it has more votes than the more "numpythonic" solution by ecatmur (but that'll probably change in time)...

Comment: How large would be a problem? I'm using this for an array of 150,000 elements and the re-ordering isn't even noticeable. Besides, its not a repeated operation. That said, I expect to have tables of several million elements in the end.

Comment: @Warrick I have to admit its faster then I would have guessed (though still best to just use lexsort), but there is another good reason against this if you arrays are really large, as this creates a list in between which will use much more RAM then the original array.

Comment: @seberg -- but the `lexsort` solution also creates an intermediate array of indices which I think would be comparable in size.

Comment: @mgilson don't think so, because `sorted` gives you a list of array objects, quite an overhead considering there are only two numbers in each of the arrays.

Comment: @seberg -- ahh right, they are array objects, but they should only be views presumably.  I don't know what the overhead of a view is compared to a `tuple` compared to whatever is returned by `lexsort` ... that's a reasonable point though.

Answer (score 3):

Just replace the whole thing (including the unique part with) for `A` being 2D:

```
A = np.ascontiguousarray(A) # just to make sure...
A = A.view([('', A.dtype)] * A.shape[1])

A = np.unique(A)
# And if you want the old view:
A = A.view(A.dtype[0]).reshape(-1,len(A.dtype))
```

I hope you are not using the `set` solution from the linked question unless you do not care too much about speed. The `lexsort` etc. is in generally great, but here not necessary since the default sort will do (if its a recarray)

---

Edit: A different view (with much the same result), but a bit more elegent maybe as no reshape is needed:

```
A = A.view([('', A.dtype, A.shape[0])])
A = np.unique(A)
# And to go back
A = A.view(A.dtype[0].base)
```

Comment: OK, I liked this method, but appearently at least at the moment `np.lexsort` is simply faster then `np.sort` on a recarray, so if efficiency is of extreme importance, I would say lexsort + custom unique (unique is very simple after sorting, check its python code) should beat everything by a lot.