# Sort bidimentional numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

The numpy arrays symbols and ocurrence both have the same size/len.

```
bidimentional_array = np.array([symbols,occurrence])
```

What I want is, do a descending sort in ocurrence and make it so that symbols index will change  in function of the sort. 
What's the most effective way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort NumPy float array column by column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496531/sort-numpy-float-array-column-by-column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.argsort` to obtain the sorting indices according to the second column and fancy indexing to obtain the sorted array:

```
bidimentional_array = bidimentional_array[np.argsort(bidimentional_array[:,1])]
```

To reverse the sorted array:

```
bidimentional_array = bidimentional_array[::-1]
```